# Image uploading from browser is fine but issue while uploading from iphone

Tags: iphone, image-uploading

I am uploading images to hosting server via browser (simple html form) the images can be uploaded without any problem but when I try to upload via iPhone it does not post the image to server.
Here is my code:

```
    NSString *urlString = @"http://example.com/fileupload.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"a.jpg\"\r\n"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imgData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];


    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    NSLog(@"Response: %@",returnString);
```

I am using the same code on a different hosting server and working fine there.
I have checked the folder has 777 permissions.

Thanks.

Comment: Start by passing a `NSError` object to `NSURLConnection` so that you can see what kind of error occurs.

Comment: what about "imgData" ??

Comment: @iManan  NSData * imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(senderImage,1);

Comment: ok fine. change -> name=\"file\".. because I've used same & it's working in my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much all for your help but the problem was on the server side. I don't know why the server sometimes rejects the file and sometimes it works fine.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove below lines, and it should work

```
 NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: done but still not working. I also have tried ASSIHTTP, NSURLCOnnection but all are not working.

Answer (score 0):

First select an image

Code ::

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *capturedImg;

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{

   NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], 1); 
   capturedImg = [UIImage imageWithData:dataImage];
}
```

For Uploading image,

Code ::

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(capturedImg, 0.8);
```

And, this `imgData` will be used for uploading image as data

Change ::

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"a.jpg\"\r\n"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; // 'userfile' to 'file'
```

Hopefully, it will help to you.

Thanks.